# Table styling when rows are inside columns

Tags: html, css, row, tablelayout

I'm wondering if it's possible to use CSS `display:table` type styles for nested divs where the rows are children of the columns. Here's an example jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UrWEn/1/

Or is there another clean method to lock together the heights of the divs in each "row" based on the largest "cell"?

For various reasons I want to avoid:

- Changing the markup.
- Setting fixed heights on the rows.
- Using Javascript.

Comment: 'rows are children of the columns.' ???

Comment: Yes, as opposed to the columns (or really cells which dictate the width of the columns) being children of the rows. It'd be useful purely for styling purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is no. Tables aren't designed to be built with columns first, so there are no styling options dealing with this kind of layout.

[html table - by rows or columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1285456/1933769)

I had to resort to using javascript to set each "cell" height to that of the highest in its "row". It's the least bad option for my application.

http://jsfiddle.net/UrWEn/4/

```
var length = $('.column').eq(0).find('.cell').length, // number of rows
    $cells; 

while (length) {
    $cells = $('.cell:nth-child('+ length +')'); // all cells in row
    $cells.height(Math.max.apply(null, $cells.map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    })));
    length--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your issue, you want table structure from div, so apply below css

```
div.column { 
    display : table-row;
    border:1px solid red;
    min-height:150px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
div.row { 
    border:1px solid green;
    width:100%;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

[`working DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/UrWEn/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I don't have the flexibility to flip the layout around like that.