# jinja2: building table by iterating down columns instead of across rows

Tags: python, jinja2

If I have the following lists:

```
headers = ['Name', 'Age']
rows = [['Johnny', 30], ['Zack', 20]]
```

I can easily make a table via Jinja2 (https://jsfiddle.net/equbh9du/1/):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for h in headers %}
        <td>{{ h }}</td>
      {% endfor %
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for row in rows %}
      <tr>
        {% for item in row %}
          <td>{{ item }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm noticing it's much easier (and more organized) to return my data as a dictionary:

```
d = {'Name': ['Johnny', 'Zack'], 'Age': [30, 20]}
```

Is there an easy way to build the table I built above using this dict. I imagine I need to finish the iteration down each column before continuing to the next column (in the example above I finish the iteration across each row before continuing to the next row).

This is the code I have so far but I'm getting a messed up table (https://jsfiddle.net/j164fqy9/1/):

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for h in d %}
        <td>{{ h }}</td>
      {% endfor %
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for h, col_values in d.items() %}
      {% for item in col_values %}
        <tr>
          <td>{{ item }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

EDIT: If HTML standard prevents iterating down columns first, then I need to construct the `headers` and `rows` from `d`. Is below the best way to do this?

```
headers = [h for h in d]
rows = [[l[i] for h, l in d.items()] for i in range(len(d['Name']))]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285456/html-table-by-rows-or-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you allways have the same number of items in `col_values` this should work fine :

```
{% for i in range(d['Name']|count) %}
    <tr>
        {% for k in d %}
            <td>{{ d[k][i] }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This looks good! Just made a minor change to the first line which accounts for proper jinja2 syntax